# member function pointer problem

Tags: c++

Works:

```
static void WINAPI ServiceStart(DWORD argc, LPTSTR* argv);

int main() {
   SERVICE_TABLE_ENTRY DispatchTable[] = {
      {"MyService", ServiceStart},
      {NULL, NULL}
   };
}
```

Doesn't work:

> error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'void (__stdcall Service::* )(DWORD,LPTSTR *)' to 'LPSERVICE_MAIN_FUNCTIONA'

```
class Service {
   static void WINAPI ServiceStart(DWORD argc, LPTSTR* argv);
};

int main() {
   SERVICE_TABLE_ENTRY DispatchTable[] = {
      {"MyService", Service::ServiceStart},
      {NULL, NULL}
   };
}
```

Comment: § 7.5.1 - "Two function types with different language linkages are distinct types even if they are otherwise identical."

Comment: The misssing semicolon after the class definition is just a copy&paste problem, right?

Comment: @awoodland: That section of the Standard is not relevant here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must use `&` in that context to obtain a correct pointer.

Answer (score 3):

Use `&Service::ServiceStart`, not `Service::ServiceStart`.

One piece of advice: since you made it a `static` function of `Service` class, rename it as well. `ServiceStart` is unnecessarily long. I think `Service` is implied here. If so, then make it just `Start`:

```
class Service
{
  static void WINAPI Start(DWORD argc, LPTSTR *argv);
};
```

And then use `&Service::Start`.